# Error: fields must be passed when initializing state, How so?

Tags: reactjs, forms

Getting this error but I can't really find an issue with my code. The error points towards the ReactDOM.render line of code. but I can't find the issue.

Re-factored my code to no avail. I went through other variable declarations and everything in my code but I can't seem to find anything that'd make the error go away!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field,reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStream } from '../../actions/index';

class StreamCreate extends React.Component {
    renderError=({error,touched})=>{
        if(touched && error){
            return (
                <div className="ui error message">
                    <div className="header">{error}</div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }


    renderInput=({ input,label,meta })=>{
        const className=`field ${meta.error && meta.touched ? 'error':''}`;
        return (<div className={className}>
                    <label>{label}</label>
                    <input {...input} autoComplete="off"/>
                    {this.renderError(meta)}
                </div>        
            );    
        }

    onSubmit=(formValues)=>{
        this.props.createStream(formValues);
    };

    //redux-form changes it all!
    render(){
        return (
                    <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} className="ui form error">
                        <Field name="title" component={this.renderInput} label="Enter Title"/>
                        <Field name="description" component={this.renderInput} label="Enter Description"/>
                        <button className="ui button primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
        );
    }
}

const validate=(formValues)=>{
    const errors={};
    if(!formValues.title){
        errors.title ='You must enter a title'
    }
    if(!formValues.description){
        errors.description='you must enter a description'
    }
    return errors;
};


const formWrapped =  reduxForm({
    form: 'streamCreate',
    validate: validate
})(StreamCreate);

export default connect(null,{ createStream })(formWrapped);

//My app.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';


import App from './components/App';
import reducers from './reducers/index';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducers,composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)));

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>,document.querySelector('#root'));

//reducers index.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import authReducer from './authReducer';


export default combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    form: formReducer 
});

//authreducer.js
import { SIGN_IN,SIGN_OUT} from '../actions/types';
const INITIAL_STATE={
    isSignedIn: null,
    userId: null
};


export default(state=INITIAL_STATE,action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case SIGN_IN:
        return {...state,isSignedIn: true, userId: action.payload };
        case SIGN_OUT:
        return {...state,isSignedIn: false, userId: null };
        default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

No error and to be able to view the page

Comment: Would you post contents of `./reducers/index` please? It should be there

Comment: Just a side note about imports, if your file name is `index.js` you don't need to specify the file name in your import. You could import that as `import reducers from './reducers';`

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Jamie-FenrirDigitalLtd Yes, I am aware of this. Since I'm using react for the first time I want to be able to reference back later on and not get confused. I have added other comments elsewhere to be able to understand. Thanks though! :)

Comment: @PredragBeocanin I've added the reducers index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Your Redux-form to Version 8.1.Because Your Code is according to Version 8.1. Redux-form is reWritten Totally in Version 6.1 .Here is the Link to Version 8.1 Guide.
[v5 → v6 Migration Guide](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/migrationguide.md/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no idea V5 was installed as i had run the normal npm install and so i assumed the latest version got installed.thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i -S redux-form@8.1
```

or if you use yarn

```
yarn add redux-form@8.1
```

**Why?**

By mistake latest tag in `redux-form` points to `5.4.0`.

```
$ yarn -s info redux-form dist-tags
{ latest:
   '5.4.0',
  rc:
   '8.0.0-0',
  old:
   '5.3.6',
  alpha:
   '7.0.0-alpha.9' }
```

The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/4405